# cors header wasn't set in request although apache server was configured

Tags: apache-2.4, cors

can anyone point me why my request header wasn't set with cors header although in apache httpd.conf was configured just to do that. Am I missing something here ?? Thanks in advance.

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "some url"  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Connection, Content-Type, Cookie, DNT, Host, Keep-Alive, Origin, Referer, User-Agent, X- CSRF Token, X-Requested-With "
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true    
    
</Directory>
```